# ios add UICollectionView reuseIdentifier error

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have add a `UICollectionView` to my view.I have implement the methed below.

**I get error:**

> "NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSIndexPath reuseIdentifier]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"

```
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"CellID";
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:10];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"V.jpg"];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I think you're missing a `return cell;` in your middle function there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"CellID";
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:10];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"V.jpg"];

    return cell; // here is ur mistake
}
```

Add `return cell;` to end.

Answer (score 1):

the cell need register to CollectionView before,

```
   [self.dateCollectionView registerClass:[DateCell Class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier];
```

see
the identifier